# YouTube video seek

Tags: lumia, video, amber-update

I can only pause and continue video, but how do I fast forward?

I have tried tapping and swipe on timeline but it doesn't work that way?

Comment: What app are you playing the YouTube videos in?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your video playing with controls? Because I've just tested and I can forward and backward the video some seconds. I just can't seek for a specific moment with granular controls but sure pause and continue are not the only controls in my case.

Comment: @NeilTurner I'm using plain IE browser in lumia-720 with amber update.

Comment: @VitorCanova screen looks almost identical to [this](http://www.mobiletechworld.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/videoplayback1.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Built-in Player

The phone's built-in video player, which is used to play videos on IE and other apps, doesn't have a seek mode like you'd expect. The **Next** and **Previous** are actually used to skip forward and backwards within a clip.

The only problem is that the buttons appear to skip a fixed amount of time, so if you're watching a short 15 second clip from YouTube, the **Next** button will most likely skip over the while clip. With longer clip of a few minutes, skipping forward and back seems to work well.

## Alternative?

If you watch a lot of YouTube videos, I would recommend [Metrotube, which is a free YouTube client for Windows Phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/metrotube/8d93224f-2808-e011-9264-00237de2db9e). It features a custom player which has the ability to seek within a clip using the on-screen controls.